# Is there a way to get the check digits of card master key or the session key used for arqc calculation from the chip card?

Tags: emv

ARQC validation is not working, I understand there could be several reasons for that, I need to first confirm I have the correct issuer master key. Is it possible to get the check digits of the key(used in arqc generation) from the chip application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah tough to analyze and correct, but unfortunately, KCV is available only for certification authority public key, not for card key or session key.